# spring with websockets PATCH

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am having an error with our spring application with websockets when we are deploying our site on Tomcat 7.0.56. I try to access the websocket endpoint path which is `application/wsconnection/ws` it shows nosuchfielderror: PATCH

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PATCH
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

but when i try to run it locally

```
Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".
```

does the error occur because of conflict with tomcat's jars? i've checked the source file of the har in `tomcat.websocket` and others but there is no `PATCH` field. what does the websocket send in handshake with the server endpoint?

servlet's path is `/wsconnection/*` and endpoint path is '/ws`.

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>3rd-party</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sn</groupId>
            <artifactId>sn-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mina-integration-spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- websocket -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.4.v20141103</version>
        </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<!-- servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/wsconnection/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 15 minutes -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- encoding filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- struts filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml/dispatcher-servlet.xml

it only contains include of other xml context.

Comment: Could you please share you pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a tomcat issue. Such exceptions indicates a versions mismatching.
Make sure you use the same version among all spring dependencies.

sharing you pom.xml,web.xml and servlet context will be helpful too.

Comment: @EhabAl-Hakwati i've updated my question with web.xml,pom.xml,and servlet

Comment: according to documentation NoSuchFieldError "Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldError.html

and digging throw spring 4.0.6 repo I found PATCH is exists

Comment: @Override
  protected void More ...service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
 
   String method = request.getMethod();
   if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(RequestMethod.PATCH.name())) {
    processRequest(request, response);
   }
   else {
    super.service(request, response);
   }
  }